# Binding a single angular expression out of a json-file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am pretty new to angularJS, and obviously there are some simple things that i do not yet understand. What i want to do is the following:

I've got a de-DE.json (that e.g. has several language-keys for a planned multi-language site) that looks somewhat like this

```
{
    "index": {
        "headline": "The title of that view",
        "tabmenu": [
            {
                "id": "home",
                "class": "active in",
                "title":"Title No. 1",
                "description":"Some description"
            },
            {
                "id": "profile",
                "class": "",
                "title":"Title No. 2",
                "banner":"WallBanner.jpg",
                "description":"Some description"
            },
            {
                "id": "messages",
                "class": "",
                "title":"Title No. 3",
                "description":"Some description"
            },
            {
                "id": "settings",
                "class": "",
                "title":"Title No. 4",
                "description":"Some description"
            }
        ]
    },
    "media": {
       ...
    }
}
```

Next have a look at my index.html that looks like:

```
<html ng-app id="ng-app">
<head>
    <title>Title of the Site</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="languageKey">
   <div class="container" ng-model="language.index">

       <h1>{{ headline }}</h1>

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-12">

               <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                   <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
               </ul>

               <div class="tab-content">
                   <div class="tab-pane fade {{ lg.class }}" id="{{ lg.id }}" ng-repeat="lg in language.index.tabmenu">
                       <h3>{{ lg.title }}</h3>
                       <p>{{ lg.description }}</p>
                   </div>
               </div>

           </div>
       </div>

   </div>

   <script src="../assets/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="../assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../assets/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#myTab a:first').tab('show')
        })

       function languageKey($scope, $http)
       {
           $http({method: 'POST', url: 'de-DE.json'}).success(function(data)
           {
               $scope.language = data; //response Data
           });
       }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So thanks to some google-knownledge the part with the `<div ng-repeat="lg in language.index.tabmenu">` works fine.

But much more common are language-keys that are just used once, without repeating html structure like in the above

```
<h1>{{ headline }}</h1> 
(I've also tried <h1 ng-bind="{headline}"
```

So is there a leightweight way to just call those expressions?

Obviously it doesn't work if i try `ng-model="language.index"` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set your JSON object in your `$scope` element inside your controller, and you can use it in the view:

```
$scope.myJSON = {...};
```

In HTML

```
<h1>{{myJSON.index.headline }}</h1>
```

By the way, if you're implementing a multi-language application take a look at [angular-translate](http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/).

Answer (score 0):

If this works

```
<div ng-repeat="lg in language.index.tabmenu">
```

then as long as you load the parsed JSON object into the `$scope` the same way, this should output the headline:

```
<h1>{{ language.index.headline }}</h1>
```

The [docs suggest](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) that `ng-model` only works with inputs:

> ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope

Comment: Thanks to both replies :)

This works fine. Sometimes the answer is more obvious than my weirdness makes me think it is ;)...